# Оператор приведения типа

Tags: c++

Как написать оператор приведения типа **к пользовательскому типу** так, чтобы в случае чего выполнялось неявное преобразование типов? То есть так же как в `operator double()` и т.п.

Comment: Покажите пример кода, из которого видно, что вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Нужен оператор приведения к типу, отличному от стандартных

Comment: Причём должно выполняться неявное преобразование в тех же ситуациях, в которых выполняется неявное преобразование у стандартных

Comment: Лично я не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Покажите код, который демонстрирует вашу проблему.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автоматическое приведение к типу для которого реализован оператор приведения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474318/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 7):

Операторы приведения к любому типу пишуются одинаково, не важно пользовательский он или нет.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A { int x; };

struct B {
    operator A() {
        A a = {1};
        return a;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a = b;
    std::cout << a.x << '\n';
}
```