# Автоматическое приведение к типу для которого реализован оператор приведения

Tags: c++

Есть два класса: `A` и `B`. Можно ли в классе `A` написать оператор приведения типа к типу `B`, т.е. что-то типа `operator B()`?

Причём так, чтобы при выполнении какой-либо операции над объектом типа `A`, которая не определена в `A`, но определена в `B`, выполнялось бы неявное преобразование объекта типа `A` к объекту типа `B`.

Comment: Будет иметь место преобразование только в тех случаях, где используется функция с параметром, имеющим тип  класса B. Два раза преобразование, сначала из класса A  в класс B, а затем из класса B еще в какой-нибудь тип, делаться не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Да, оператор такой вы можете сделать. Вы можете написать любой оператор приведения какой захотите, в рамках языка естественно.

Нет, для выполнения операции не определенной для `A`, но определенной для `B` неявно оператор приведения вызываться не будет. Для Си++ каждый объект имеет только один тип. Приведение к типу это на самом деле создание нового объекта. Всегда.

В данном случае необходимо выполнять явное приведение к типу `B`:

```
A a;
static_cast<B>(a).function_from_B();
```

Comment: Ну, хм. Вот так катит за «неявный» вызов: http://ideone.com/CovwOv? Хотя насчёт _любой_ операции это ТС погорячился, да.

Comment: @VladD Под "неявно, как вы описали" я имел в виду второй абзац из вопроса, поэтому ваш пример не катит.

Comment: Угу, я понял. C++ сложный язык, поэтому точный ответ был бы, кажется, «в некоторых случаях работает, в некоторых нет, точный список не знает никто».